# Inline codes are not highlighted after using "knit html" function in Rstudio

Tags: html, css, markdown, knitr

I wrote an `.Rmd` file with some inline codes quoted by "`", and I used the `knit html` function in Rstudio to convert the `.Rmd` file to `.html`. However, the inline codes were not highlighted as on *stackoverflow*, and I took a look at the source codes of the `.html` file and found that the setting was like

```
tt, code, pre {
font-family: 'DejaVu Sans Mono', 'Droid Sans Mono', 'Lucida Console', Consolas, Monaco, monospace;
}
```

And I tried altering this block:

```
tt, code, pre {
font-family: 'DejaVu Sans Mono', 'Droid Sans Mono', 'Lucida Console', Consolas, Monaco, monospace;
background-color: #F8F8F8;
}
```

And it worked.

However, I do not want to do such work every time after I knit the `.Rmd` file to `.html`. I have read the help files of `knit2html` and `markdownHTMLOptions` in R but found no solution. Is there any solution to this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the latest version of the `markdown` package on CRAN, you can use the `header` argument to add additional CSS code to the HTML output, e.g.

```
library(knitr)
knit2html(...,
  header = c('<style type="text/css">', 'code{background-color: #F8F8F8;}', '</style>'))
```

Or just set this as a global option in your `~/.Rprofile`:

```
options(markdown.HTML.header = c('<style type="text/css">', 'code{background-color: #F8F8F8;}', '</style>'))
```

And the `markdown` package will use it every time when you simply run `knit2html()` without explicitly specifying the `header` argument.

With RStudio, it is a little trickier. See the documentation [Customizing Markdown Rendering](http://www.rstudio.com/ide/docs/authoring/markdown_custom_rendering).