# After I made some modifications on the CSS stylesheet, Rmarkdown failed to render the LaTeX formula

Tags: css, r, markdown, knitr, rstudio

Last time I asked a question about how to customize the inline code using `knitr` and `Rmarkdown` in `Rstudio`.([Inline codes are not highlighted after using “knit html” function in Rstudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18744985/inline-codes-are-not-highlighted-after-using-knit-html-function-in-rstudio)). As suggested in [this page](http://www.rstudio.com/ide/docs/authoring/markdown_custom_rendering), I have added the following lines of codes in `~/.Rprofile`

```
# assert my own stylesheet for knit-html in Rstudio
options(rstudio.markdownToHTML=
    function(inputFile,outputFile){
        require(markdown)
        markdownToHTML(inputFile,outputFile,stylesheet='~/.css/Rstudio.css')
    }
)
```

And my own `.css` file is:

```
body, td {
   font-family: sans-serif;
   background-color: white;
   font-size: 15px;
   margin: 8px;
   line-height: 200%;
}

code {
   font-family: 'DejaVu Sans Mono', 'Droid Sans Mono', 'Lucida Console', Consolas, Monaco, monospace;
   color: rgb(255,0,50);
   background-color: #F8F8F8;
   outline-style: solid;
   outline-width: thin;
   outline-color: lightgrey;
   padding-left: 0.8mm;
   padding-right: 0.8mm;
   padding-left: 0.3mm;
   padding-right: 0.3mm;
   margin-left: 0.5mm;
   margin-right: 0.5mm;
}

tt, pre {
   font-family: 'DejaVu Sans Mono', 'Droid Sans Mono', 'Lucida Console', Consolas, Monaco, monospace;
}

h1 {
   font-size:2.2em;
}

h2 {
   font-size:1.8em;
}

h3 {
   font-size:1.4em;
}

h4 {
   font-size:1.0em;
}

h5 {
   font-size:0.9em;
}

h6 {
   font-size:0.8em;
}

a:visited {
   color: rgb(50%, 0%, 50%);
}

pre {   
   margin-top: 0;
   max-width: 95%;
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
   white-space: pre-wrap;
}

pre code {
   display: block; padding: 0.5em;
}

code.r, code.cpp {
   background-color: #F8F8F8;
}

table, td, th {
  border: none;
}

blockquote {
   color:#666666;
   margin:0;
   padding-left: 1em;
   border-left: 0.5em #EEE solid;
}

hr {
   height: 0px;
   border-bottom: none;
   border-top-width: thin;
   border-top-style: dotted;
   border-top-color: #999999;
}

@media print {
   * {
      background: transparent !important;
      color: black !important;
      filter:none !important;
      -ms-filter: none !important;
   }

   body {
      font-size:12pt;
      max-width:100%;
   }

   a, a:visited {
      text-decoration: underline;
   }

   hr {
      visibility: hidden;
      page-break-before: always;
   }

   pre, blockquote {
      padding-right: 1em;
      page-break-inside: avoid;
   }

   tr, img {
      page-break-inside: avoid;
   }

   img {
      max-width: 100% !important;
   }

   @page :left {
      margin: 15mm 20mm 15mm 10mm;
   }

   @page :right {
      margin: 15mm 10mm 15mm 20mm;
   }

   p, h2, h3 {
      orphans: 3; widows: 3;
   }

   h2, h3 {
      page-break-after: avoid;
   }
```

The inline codes finally turn out to be formatted as what I want. However, I failed to get LaTeX formula rendered in Rmarkdown after that. For example, `$\alpha$` yields the plain text "$\alpha$"! I have tried to disable the added lines in `~/.Rprofile`, and then the formula can be rendered successfully again. 
Seems something wrong with my `.css` file but not Rstudio, since I tried to use the function `knit2html("test.Rmd",stylesheet="~/.css/Rstudio.css")` and the formulae were not rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Is that your full css file?

You are missing a closing } for your @media query, that could be causing some negative effects.